# Changing color of TabHost/TabWidget

Tags: java, android, colors, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I'm having a really hard time changing the color of my TabWidget. I've looked at several posts and tried them out, but none of them worked for me. I'm trying to change the default (blue) color scene to green.

[Image of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyTcK.png)

My xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to change the color of the tabs programmatically is by using

```
for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                           .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00304E"));
}
```

To change the color of the currently selected tab,

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
                       .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008EE8"));
```

Comment: Not yet. I don't have that much free time right now. I'll test it upcoming friday